# Content of Excel cells to HTML

Tags: php, mysql, excel, import

I have a question which is (I think) not easy to solve.

I have an Excel-sheet (.xls) that contains multiple columns and multiple rows. The Excel-file is derived from an export from a database. Within that export all the HTML-tags are stripped from the content so when you open the Excel-file all you see is text and not any HTML-tags or whatever can be confusing for somebody without any knowledge of HTML.

After doing some changes to the Excel-file the Excel-file must be imported again into the database. Now the question comes: is it possible to place back the stripped HTML?

We are using PHP 5.3 on a MySQL-database. To read the data from the Excel-file we use [php-excel-reader](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/)

Is there please anyone who knows if there is a solution for this?

Comment: if you open it with a text editor like notepad++ and edit it?

Comment: can you explain me more what you mean by that?

Comment: I have to write an answer because it was too long to explain here

Answer (score 0):

if you open a file exported by MySQL you will see the structure, something like

```
    1,,'john','Quesada'
    2,'t@t.com',,'Fonseca'
    3,,'Gabriel','Smith'
....
```

so the Idea is open this in a text editor and make find and replace, I.E you can find-replace and change all the fields with (empty space) for `Insert into t1 values (` so the file will looks like

```
Insert into t1 values (1,,'john','Quesada'
Insert into t1 values (2,'t@t.com',,'Fonseca'
Insert into t1 values (3,,'Gabriel','Smith'
```

you do that and at the end you have the file as you want to,

try doing that with your file, try to open it with a text editor and customize it how you want to.

Comment: You will need to finish your lines too, and IFC it will be better to work with regexp. Not sure tho, this is the question here.

Comment: @user1496048 did you try to open the file with a text editor and added the HTML manually?

Answer (score 0):

If you stripped the HTML tags while you export the content, it seems hard to recover it after, if you don't save it somewhere. Are you modifying the column containing the HTML content, if no, then you should just remove those column from the export, otherwise you will have to export without striping tags, maybe changing the separators.

Comment: Hey all,

First, thanks for all your comments, cheers to yourself :)

It's not like exporting data from MySQL to an Excel as usually, we are exporting data from a query, strip the HTML-tags from ALL the columns and rows and after that we the Excel-file. So we have an excel-file, make some changes and import it again and except for the changes everything should be as it was before including the stripped HTML-tags...